# Android raise Notification when app goes to background (not single activity)

Tags: android, android-activity, background, notifications

I have an Android app made of 3 activities A, B and C:

- A is the application itself (a regular Activity)
- B is the settings screen (made with PreferenceActivity)
- C is the about screen (a regular Activity)

The relationship between the activities is as follows:

- A is the main activity
- B's parent is A
- C's parent is B

Activity A raises a notification when going to background, this is accomplished by calling NotificationManager's notify() inside A's onStop() method.

When the user launches the app it starts from activity A, then if the user presses the home button the notification will be raised as soon as the home screen is shown. Clicking on the notification will get the user back to the app.

Everything seems to work but now there's a behaviour I tend not to like:
When the user launches the app and then goes to settings (therefore showing activity A and then B) the notification is also raised (because A has gone to background in order to show B).

This is not desired: The notification should be raised only when the application goes to background regardless of the activity the user was looking at.

How to implement this proper behaviour?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: can you please post what you have tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a boolean flag `shouldNotify` and set it to false when you are opening one of your other Activities. Without your code I can't tell you exactly how to implement it but here is an example to get the idea accross:

```
private boolean shouldNotify = true;

@Override 
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    shouldNotify = true;
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(shouldNotify){
        sendNotification();
    }
}


// Where you need to put these next snippets depends on how you've made your Activity

/*
 * Launching settings activity
 */
shouldNotify = false;
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, YourSettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear thanks. I'll then have to raise the notification inside each activity's onStop(), right? Or is there a more concise way to avoid repeating code?

Comment: Thanks I did it following your advice and also the advice of @benjamin-k in his previous answer (extending the Application class).

One little caveat: I had to put the sendNotification() call in onPause() and not in onStart() otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a boolean flag which is checked before raising the notification and set it to "false" before startig Activity B.

Of course this way you would have to do the same in Activity B and C for them to raise the notification, too.

Or, as hinted to before you could implement an own application class and fetch the callback there.

Comment: Letting B and C raise the notification as well leads to duplicated code between activities, how to avoid?

Could you please post a link to the second alternative you proposed?

Comment: Well, the application object is (simplified) an application-wide singleton object which the android system instantiates and guarantees for it being a single instance. From your activities you can access it via mActivity.getApplication().

To implement your own code you have to implement your own subclass of Application and register it in the android manifest 


<application android:name="com.ibm.blueshop.controller.MyApplicationSubclass"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

For further info read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html